# Sequelize query with where inside include

Tags: node.js, express, sequelize.js

I have the following models:

```
'use strict';

module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
    var Collection = sequelize.define("Collection", {
        name: DataTypes.STRING,
        customer: DataTypes.STRING
    }, {
        classMethods: {
            associate: function(models) {
                Collection.hasMany(models.Items);
            }
        }
    });

    return Collection;
};


'use strict';

module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
    var Item = sequelize.define("Item", {
        itemId: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING,
            primaryKey: true
        }
    }, {
        classMethods: {
            associate: function(models) {
                Item.belongsToMany(models.Collection);
            }
        }
    });

    return Item;
};
```

Lets say I want to get all the collections and their items with specific customer and one of the items contains the itemId. 
My query is as follows:

```
models.Collection.findAll({
    where: {
      customer: customerParam
    },
    include: [{
        model: models.Item,
        where: {
          itemId: itemParam
        }
    }]
}).then(function(collections) {
    console.log(collections);
})
```

The problem is that this query filters the items from the collections that I got and now they only contain the items which are with the same itemId instead of containing all the items of the collection.

Answer (score 15):

You get this result due to the where statements in your query are executed separately like subqueries.
So, if you want to generate where clause like it `WHERE Collection.customer = 'blabla' AND Item.itemId = 1` you should do the following:

```
models.Collection.findAll({
    where: {
      customer: customerParam,
      '$items.itemId$': itemParam
    },
    include: [{
        model: models.Item,
        as: 'items'
    }]
})
```

Comment: It is now throwing the following exception when I activate the query:
Unhandled rejection Error: Item (items) is not associated to Collection!

Comment: Helped me a lot just adding query like  '$items.itemId$': itemParam worked. Great. Thanks a lot.